# Where should I place local executables on macOS?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, path

I often write system-wide scripts and I wonder where to place my executables on macOS.

On many Linux system, `/usr/local/bin` (also `/usr/local/sbin`) is usually empty and I place my executables in there.
But on macOS, `/usr/local/bin` has already contained a lot of executables provided by such as [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).
I understand `/usr/local/bin` is the most proper directory to place executables locally installed and similar questions also are answered `/usr/local/bin`, but I feel hesitant to contaminate by mixing my executables.
Is it good manner to place my executables in `/usr/local/bin` in spite of many other executables existing?

In other way, I am wondering where is the second best directory to place my executables.
I think `/opt/bin` is the second best at the moment because `/opt/bin` seems to proper directory to place my executables by its purpose and `/opt/bin` does not exist by default on macOS (empty assured).

Is there any idea or advice about my wondering?

**similar questions** (answered `/usr/local/bin` is best):

- [Where do you keep your own scripts on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682413/where-do-you-keep-your-own-scripts-on-osx)
- [Where should I cp oc binary to on MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351776/where-should-i-cp-oc-binary-to-on-macos)

Comment: I like `~/.local/bin` as described in the [systemd file hierarchy](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html), extending the [XDG spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/). Doesn't require special permissions, keeps `~` clutter free, but is still easy to find.

Comment: @BenjaminW.
Thank you for your opinion!
I have been using `~/.local/bin` too for many years.
I agree completely that this is smart way for personal use executables.
But I wondered where to place system-wide my executables.

Comment: Oh, system wide, right! Symlinks into `/usr/local/bin` is what I do for that.

Comment: @BenjaminW.
Thanks again. mattficle answered and showed the concrete way to symlink `/usr/local/bin`. I will follow the way you and mattficle suggested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Homebrew doesn't directly install packages to the normal locations in `/usr/local/`, it installs to its own directory (`/usr/local/Cellar` by default) and then symlinks the files to `/usr/local/bin` (or `lib`, `opt`, and so on).

You could follow this pattern and create your own directory in `usr/local/` to store your executables, and then symlink them to `/usr/local/bin`. This would let you keep all your own files organized in one place without needing to add a new directory to your $PATH.

Comment: @mattficle
That's a smart idea. I love it!
I worried about I could not separate easily my executables from another executables after mixing those.
The way you suggested is solved my worry completely.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I really like this solution! I think it's better than the usual solution of mixing your executables into one of the standard folders